# How to set Tor -> Socks with proxychain correctly on Tails?

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

Goal: Tor Browser -> Socks5 proxy
OS: Tails

For testing purposes I have chosen a socks proxy from here (e.g. 159.253.191.110:61111).

I installed proxychains, then edited the config file:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install proxychains
nano /etc/proxychains.conf
```

There I added my proxy below the Tor proxy:

```
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 159.253.191.110 61111
```

Now I wanted to run proxychains

```
proxychains tor
```

I was shown this  ...

```
 ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been     
 This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  
 That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as 
 possible. Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 
 127.0.0.1:9050 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [warn] Could not bind to 
 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running? Nov 30 
 18:
 33:23.480 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9061: 
 Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 
 127.0.0.1:9062
 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9062: 
 Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
 Nov 30 18:33:23.480 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9150: Address 
 already in use. Is Tor already running
 #etc.
```

... so I decided to 'sudo killall tor' and run 'proxychains tor' again:

```
 root@amnesia:/home/amnesia# proxychains tor
 ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
 Nov 30 18:45:40.215 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.4-rc 
 (git-6c4f0850146d706c)running 
 on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1e and Zlib 1.2.7.

 Nov 30 18:45:40.215 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! 
 Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download
 /download#warning

 Nov 30 18:45:40.215 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".

 Nov 30 18:45:40.218 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication  
 method 
 has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can 

 reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor  
 controller as soon as possible.

 Nov 30 18:45:40.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050

 Nov 30 18:45:40.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061

 Nov 30 18:45:40.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062

 Nov 30 18:45:40.218 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

 Nov 30 18:45:40.219 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353

 Nov 30 18:45:40.219 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 
 127.0.0.1:9040

 Nov 30 18:45:40.219 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051

 Nov 30 18:45:40.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/g     eoip.

 Nov 30 18:45:40.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/g     eoip6.

 Nov 30 18:45:40.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, 
 and you probably shouldn't.

 |DNS-response|: amnesia is not exist

 |DNS-response|: amnesia is not exist

 |DNS-response|: amnesia is not exist

 Nov 30 18:45:40.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting

 Nov 30 18:45:41.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to server
 ============================================================       
 T=1448909141

 (Sandbox) Caught a bad syscall attempt (syscall fcntl64)

 tor(+0x1587d9)[0xf764f7d9]

 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fcntl+0x36)[0xf61f8036]

 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fcntl+0x36)[0xf61f8036]

 /usr/lib/libproxychains.so.3(connect+0x1a3)[0xf65440f3]

 tor(+0xdfa69)[0xf75d6a69]

 root@amnesia:/home/amnesia#
```

Obviously now Socks Listener is working, but how do I resolve the other things like "Caught a syscall attemp"

I am desperately trying to get this working and really would appreciate any help (the easier explained the better as I am starting with Tails).

How do I get it done so that my socks adress is actually shown as ip?

I am looking forward to your answers!

Comment: You specified Tor's SOCKS address as a proxychains proxy, then tried to run Tor through proxychains. This won't work for the same reason as plugging an extension cord into itself...

Comment: LOL 12 more to go...